# Create and trigger a window event automatically

Tags: javascript

How to create and triggent an event in javascript ?

For example I imagine something like this:

```
window['myevent'] = function() {alert('myevent was triggered automatically');}
window['myevent'](window);
```

basically i want to create my event and trigger it when i need automatically in a function

Comment: Have you googled 'query user events'?

Comment: @TobyAllen, no he hasn't, probably he didn't know the terminologies to the precision, that's why he has posted a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works (did you try it) but there is no need to pass the (window) argument - your function/event isn't expecting an argument.

```
window['myevent']();
```

There is a more formal guide [here at SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/) which demonstrates using `addEventListener` with custom events, and using `dispatchEvent` to trigger the event on an element.

Note: IE 9 and below do not support the `CustomEvent` object. If you are using a JS Library, however, then most libraries support some form of custom event delegation.